# SQL query and stored procedure not producing desired results

Tags: sql, database, stored-procedures, sybase

I have this table and Stored proc function:

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE _DMigNumbers(
    Number numeric(20,0) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
);
INSERT INTO _DMigNumbers VALUES(0)
```

Stored proc function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION read_and_increment()
RETURNS NUMERIC(20,0)
BEGIN
    DECLARE @number_just_read NUMERIC(20,0);

      SELECT number INTO @number_just_read
        FROM _DMigNumbers;

      UPDATE _DMigNumbers
         SET number = number + 1;
   RETURN @number_just_read;
End
```

and I create this Numbers table as well

```
CREATE TABLE _Numbers (
    Number int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
);
INSERT INTO _Numbers VALUES(1)
INSERT INTO _Numbers VALUES(2)
INSERT INTO _Numbers VALUES(3)
INSERT INTO _Numbers VALUES(4)
```

NOW:

when I do this:

```
select 
    f.Number
    ,read_and_increment()
from _Numbers f
```

I get :

```
  Number-----Value

   1          0   
   2          0   
   3          0   
   4          0
```

I want different value like (0,1,2,3) - what do I need to do to achieve this?

I understand that I am getting the same values because of the single Select, but not sure what I need to do to get what I am after at the moment......

I cannot use IDENTITY or autoincrement see [my previous question for more details if interested...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3151548/sql-stored-proc-help-me-write-this-one-please-part-2)

Thanks,

Voodoo

Comment: that seems like voodoo programming. afaik, this is the first time i've seen that kind of query(updating while doing select) question here in SO

Comment: Based on the accepted answer from the other post it looks like you're missing a commit statement.  Does that take place automatically in Sybase?

Comment: I don't have access to Sybase, so I can't run that code.  However in SQL Server you can't make a function like that, you'd get the error: `Invalid use of side-effecting or time-dependent operator in 'UPDATE' within a function.`  I'm not sure how you'd do that in Sybase.

Comment: I tried it with MySQL, and got NULL in the second column.

Comment: @g.d.d.c: the results are same with or without the commit statement.

Comment: What do you get if you run several individual select statements that just select your `read_and_increment()` proc?  Does it behave as expected when used without another table involved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try marking your function as `NOT DETERMINISTIC` and see if that helps.  By default, all functions are deterministic, which means the database server can cache the result under certain circumstances.  Marking it this way will force the server to re-evaluate the query/function each time.

```
CREATE FUNCTION read_and_increment()
RETURNS NUMERIC(20,0)
NOT DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE @number_just_read NUMERIC(20,0);

      SELECT number INTO @number_just_read
        FROM _DMigNumbers;

      UPDATE _DMigNumbers
         SET number = number + 1;
   RETURN @number_just_read;
End
```

Comment: DUDE that is just brilliant, it seems to have worked. Man I wish I could give you a +100. AMAZING!

Comment: Just want to say that this did work for me, thank you very much - really appreciate the help!!!